# Are there names for math problems where inputs are rendered vertically vs. horizontally?

Tags: terminology

I could set up a simple math problem in multiple ways. If I wanted to add $2$ and $3$, for instance, I could write:

> $2 + 3 =$ __

Or I could write:

> $2$
> $+3$

Are there words to denote these different renderings?

Comment: None that I know of. You could [edit ]the question to explain why the name matters.

Comment: names don’t matter; it’s just addition, but in my primary school days we had the second way of writing (to get us to practice the ‘addition algorithm’ of ‘carrying over’). and in math papers, the second is used purely to save space/ clearly organize the billions of terms so we can easily see what cancels out etc.

Comment: I can't say the name really matters. I'm asking ChatGPT to set up problems, and I'd just like an easy way to tell it how I want the problems to look.

Answer (score 1):

There's a section on it here:

[Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Terms)

The vertical style is called *columnar*.

I want to know what the 'apples' version is called (top of Wikipedia page)!

Comment: Everything vertical is called columnar.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez; and everything horizontal...? (I doubt its  'rowular' - could be 'flat').

Comment: “Row-based” seems to be a popular description of this